# How does Rails and Ember integration work, do all the ember files get combined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'v seen some larger emberjs implementations like discourse: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse

Can someone explain to me how this gets integration into rails?

What happens behind the scenes when the asset gets compiled?  To the files just get minified and merged or there is more to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read about **[Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)**.

The directory you linked to above is included by the various require lines in **[`app/assets/javascripts/main_include.js`](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/main_include.js)**, which is itself included by **[`app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb`](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb#L27)**.

The gem doing the heavy lifting (the one responsible for interpreting the require lines) is **[Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets)**.

> What happens behind the scenes when the asset gets compiled? To the files just get minified and merged or there is more to it?

Between the asset pipeline docs and sprockets' docs, your very general question should be more than answered. In a nutshell, **yes**, the files are minified and merged, and **yes** there is a whole lot more to it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reading about the Asset Pipeline and Sprockets (which handle JS minification, etc), also take a look at the ember-rails gem: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails

> ember-rails allows you to include Ember.JS into your Rails 3.1+ application. The gem will also pre-compile your handlebars templates when building your asset pipeline. It includes development and production copies of Ember.